# How to ask "Can you come pick me up" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

How do I ask "Can you come pick me up?" For example, I am at work and would like to call one of my friends and ask him to pick me up. I would like to know both the most common way to say it and the formal way to say it.
From my informal education, I have heard people say:

- Можешь меня подобрать?
- Можешь меня забрать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Можешь заехать за мной?

is a usual sentence. **Забрать** is more colloquial,but it's also used.**Подобрать** means *to pick you up on the way to some place*.In some situations **подвезти** (to give someone a lift) would also do

The first sentence is neutral and can be used in every situation. If you are asking a friend, take it unchanged. In a more formal way you would say.

> Не могли бы Вы заехать за мной?

Or, meaning "give a lift

> Не могли бы Вы подвезти меня?

Забрать и подобрать should be used addressing a friend.They are highly colloquial. –

Comment: If you are a native Russian speaker, please tell me what is the most common and simplest way to ask this question. I would like to know the most colloquial way to say it. Please specify which of the verbs is the most formal way to say it, as when asking complete strangers or people that you highly respect.

Comment: I am a native Russian speaker. The first sentence is neutral and can be used in every situation. If you are asking a friend, take it unchanged. In a more formal way you would say.Не могли бы Вы заехать за мной? Or, meaning "give a lift"Не могли бы Вы подвезти меня?Забрать и подобрать should be used addressing a friend.They are highly colloquial.

Comment: Why do you capitalize "вы" in your sentences? I have never seen it capitalized in the middle of a sentence before.

Comment: It is not always capitalized. In fiction it's not capitalized.
It is customary to capitalize it in formal letters, when you show respect to the unknown person or in personal letters.  It's gradually becoming a matter of personal preference when addressing someone though.